# cdkDropListConnectedTo doesn't work if dropLists dynamically change while an item is dragged

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, drag, angular-cdk

I have several drop lists which are connected by cdkDropListConnectedTo by ids (array of strings).
... cdkDropList [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="connectableIds$ | async" ...

There's a list of orders that is not changed. But when I start dragging an order, there's a calendar view that is updated to the date of the order being dragged. So when I start dragging, the week in calendar is set to be appropriate to the order's date.

Inside the calendar there's @viewChildren that is looking for all new dropLists that appeared after the week has been updated to the order's date (in the calendar each date slot is a dropList and I need to be able to drop order into the slot).

But if switching calendar date happans, than it's not possible to drop anything onto slots. Even though I'm listening to changes of viewChildren (so when there's new ids, I dynamically update connectableIds$). But it doesn't matter, new ids appearing in the connectableIds$ do not affect droppability. You have to put order back and than drag it again (so the schedule view was previously set to the order's date and you don't need to do the week jump in the calendar).

I thought there might be an issue with change detection, but it doesn't look like that (tried playing with changeDetection component metadata and colling detectChanges manually).

Also tried switching to cdkDropListGroup, but it didn't work (probably because of nestedness: orders and calendar are placed into separate components).

I've read there was an issue with cdk dnd and scrolling while dragging, it seems to be close to what I have, but their solutions are not applicable in this case. Ideally I just would need a method I could call after drag start to force cdkDropList of orders to "recalculate"/"reindex"/"whatever" to be connected to new dropLists after calendar jump. Again, ids are updated, it's not the problem, for some reason drag and drop doesn't work even though the order drop list has new ids of slot dropLists.